# Clearing cache of a specific device (GPU) using torch

Tags: python, torch

I am using ddp to run a program where i want my main model to run on 3 devices (say GPU 0,1,2) and another aiding model to run on a separate device (say GPU3)
Earlier i was having trouble with the out of memory error on GPU 0 but using `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` solved the problem. However since the code using ddp is running on device 0,1,2 the same error now comes but only with device 3
Basically i need a way to somehow **clear the cache for a specific cuda device**. Is there a way to do so ?

I tried looking at the official torch documentation, however torch.cuda.empty_cache seems to clear the cache of only the device it is run from and not all devices.